# Cannot get polygon to show on MapFragment in Android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to draw a simply polygon on a MapFragment but cannot get it to render. I am using the code example from the [developer docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon#getZIndex%28%29) but to no avail. I am new to this so I must be missing something very obvious but I cannot work out what it is. I am not getting any runtime errors.

Here is the relevant bit of my main activity.

```
public class UserLocation<MainActivity> extends Activity  {

blah blah...

//Set up initial map fragment view
    map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    
    LatLng startPoint = new LatLng(-30.89,24.26);
    
    
    
    //See use of CameraPosition.Builder here which gives a cool perspective view on the map. See use of map.animateCamera using this method too;
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(startPoint).tilt(60).zoom(6).bearing(0).
            build();
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    
    
    //try add polgyon
    
    List<LatLng> points = Arrays.asList(new LatLng(18.39416, -33.97885),
            new LatLng(18.45116, -33.97885), 
            new LatLng(18.45116, -33.91077), 
            new LatLng(18.39416, -33.91077), 
            new LatLng(18.39416, -33.97885));
    
    PolygonOptions options = new PolygonOptions();
    options.addAll(points);
    options.fillColor(Color.RED);
    map.addPolygon(options);
```

The xml file

> ```
>   <TextView
>       android:id="@+id/header"
>       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:text="@string/hello_world" />
>
>
>   <fragment
>       android:id="@+id/map"
>       class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:layout_height="match_parent"
>       
>       />
>               <ImageButton
>     android:id="@+id/mainNavigationButton"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
>     android:onClick="OnClick_launch_mainNavigation"
>     android:alpha="0.8"
>     android:src="@drawable/copbutton"/>
>   
>   
>    
>       
> <Spinner
>       android:id="@+id/spinner1"
>       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
>       android:entries="@array/crime_arrays"
>       android:prompt="@string/crime_prompt" />
>
>       
>               </FrameLayout>
> ```

The documents would suggest this is a simple process but I'm stumped. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

your code should work. Could be, that you accidently switching your longitude/latitude, since  you are drawing the polygons to (24.26,-30.89) but move your camera to (-30.89,24.26).

To ensure your at the right area, create a button which calls

```
 private function onButtonClick(){
    LatLng startPoint = new LatLng(24.26,-30.89);
   CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(startPoint).tilt(60).zoom(6).bearing(0).
        build();
   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
 }
```

Comment: Boy, that was so simple! It was the Lat, Long order. Thanks a million.

Comment: You re welcome. happened to me too and it took days to found it. Please mark the answer as correct to solve the issue